# Image doesnt want to show up

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website and I ran into an issue where I want to use CSS to set a background image as my website is mostly transparent.  I cannot manage to display the image on the main container on my webpage as a placeholder.

Code for the Container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* background: rgba(41.6, 52.2, 60, 0.9); */
  background-image: url("Assets/Images/placeholder.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 113vh;
}
```

I have also tried doing `background-image: url("placeholder.png");` and putting the image into the main folder as the index.html

Comment: Did you try ("/placeholder.png")

Comment: Thank you that fixed it... I feel dumb asf rn ahaha

Comment: happens to all of us haha, do not sweat it